# Spark find max scale of each column

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

This is what I have done so far

```
private List<Integer> getScales(Dataset<Row> columnLengthDataFrame, 
                                Dataset<Row> df) {

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < columnLengthDataFrame.columns().length; i++) {
        Object data = df.first().get(i);
        String number = String.valueOf(data);
        if (number.contains(".")) {
            String scale = number.substring(number.indexOf(".")).substring(1);
            list.add(scale.length());
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

This gives scale of only first row and I want max of scale of same column

[image]

In case of `col1`, I am gettig scale 1 but I want scale 6.

Comment: Do you mean to find scale for only Decimal type fields or Float and Double type fields too?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to perform any action to find it out. It can be retrieved from DataFrame's schema.

> Scala

```
df.schema.fields.collect { case StructField(_, typ: DecimalType, _, _) => typ.scale }
```

> Java

```
Arrays.stream(df.schema().fields())
                .filter(f -> f.dataType().getClass().equals(DecimalType.class))
                .map(column -> ((DecimalType) column.dataType()).scale()).collect(Collectors.toList())
```